# Proof that two curves intersect in an interval based on inequality between derivatives and function's initial values

Tags: calculus, analysis

> If $f_1(a) >f_2(a)$ and $ \frac{df_2}{dx} > \frac{df_1}{dx}$ for $x \in \left[ a, \infty \right]$ , proof that there exists exists an $x \in \left[ a , \infty \right]$ such that $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$

This is a result I hypothesized  from looking at graphs.

Here is my attempt at a proof:

Integrating the inequality on derivatives on the set $(a,x)$:

$$ f_2(x) - f_2(a) > f_1(x) - f_1(a)$$

Then,

$$ f_1(x) - f_2(x) < f_1(a) - f_2(a) \tag{1}$$

From the inequality on the functions,

$$ f_1 (a) - f_2(a) >0 \tag{2}$$

Now, how do I proceed?

---

Thank you @Quasi for the counterexample, let me refine the statement a bit more, the new condition on derivative is:

$$ \frac{df_2}{dx} > \frac{df_1}{dx} >0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a counterexample, try
$$a=1,\;\;\;\;f_1(x)=1-\frac{1}{x},\;\;\;\;f_2(x)=-\frac{2}{x}$$

Comment: Nice, I've refined my conditions now. Thank you for the invaluable counter example

Comment: @Buraian: I've revised the counterexample to match the conditions of your refimed version.

Comment: I give up haha, it seems there is no way I can fix patch the holes now